# customize the display of an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an SQL query which return this result:

[image]

but I want to display it like that

[image]

How I can do that in PHP, I was tried but I found some difficulty with value 'Semaine X' that will became the name of table Column and the value of 'libelleCategorieClient' that can not repet 
Thank You,

Comment: What's the structure of the query results?  Arrays? Objects? Objects within arrays?

Comment: it's an objects, it's too long becouse I have many table in my DB: `SELECT DISTINCT cat.libelleCategorieClient, sum(ligne.quantiteLigneCommande * ligne.prixLigneCommande) AS montant,sem.libelleSemaine FROM CategorieClient cat,Client c, commande cmd,lignecommande ligne,semaine sem WHERE cat.idCategorieClient=c.idCategorieClient AND c.idClient=cmd.idClient AND cmd.idCommande=ligne.idCommande AND sem.idSemaine=cmd.idSemaine group by cat.libelleCategorieClient,sem.libelleSemaine`

Comment: this query return the table above

Comment: What you're looking for is known as a "pivot table"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to turn rows into columns (Pivoting) assuming libelleCategorieClient is unique, try the following:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', 'pass');
    $q = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT cat.libelleCategorieClient,
            sum(ligne.quantiteLigneCommande * ligne.prixLigneCommande) AS montant, 
            sem.libelleSemaine 
            FROM CategorieClient cat,Client c, commande cmd,
            lignecommande ligne,semaine sem 
            WHERE cat.idCategorieClient=c.idCategorieClient 
            AND c.idClient=cmd.idClient AND cmd.idCommande=ligne.idCommande 
            AND sem.idSemaine=cmd.idSemaine 
            GROUP BY cat.libelleCategorieClient, sem.libelleSemaine");
    $sem=array();
    $client=array();
    while($row=$q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $sem[$row['cat.libelleCategorieClient']][$row['libelleSemaine']] = $row['montant'];
        $client[$row['cat.libelleCategorieClient']]= $row['libelleCategorieClient'];
    }
    $semkey=key($sem);

    echo '<table>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th>Cetegories Clients</th>';
    foreach($sem[$semkey] as $keys=>$vals){ 
            echo '<th>'.$keys.'</th>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';

    foreach($sem as $key=>$val){
           echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$client[$key].'</td>';
            foreach($val as $v){
                echo '<td>'.$v.'</td>';
            }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: thank you so much Mawia HL that's working